# Projects based on Solana forks

Tags: ecosystem

Does anyone know what projects are currently out there that are building some blockchain based on fork of Solana?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for another Blockchain that forked the actual Solana blockchain codebase? Or projects that are still building on top of other assorted Solana labs created code based?

Comment: I was specifically looking for the former. Projects that forked the Solana codebase, and will be using core features such as PoH, TowerBFT etc in their own (probably special-purpose) Solana-like blockchain...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is or is akin to a "status update" which will have little future value

Answer (score 2):

Velas is built on top of the Solana code base, and they added EVM compatibility. I'm not aware of others, though I'm sure there are more.